# define clear function for win32 && linux

Tags: c, linux, winapi

My question should not be too hard to answer:

I am trying to write a C program just to train up some C skills.
However I can't tell on which system this program will run in the future.

I want to make sure I have covered both Unix and DOS systems.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
   #define clear()
       system("cls");
#endif // _WIN32

#ifdef linux
    #define clear()
       system("clear");
#endif // linux
```

This seems to be wrong, as it tells me

```
expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant"
```

Although I'm not sure if I am doing it right at all with this definitions (I could include 2 separate headers here for example >> more memory used)

There must be kind of a hard newbish syntax error here.

Comment: Please repost your code using code markup, not quotation. Use the `{ }` tool in the SO editor tomark code for literal display.

Comment: The expansion of a macro has to be on the same line as `#define`, unless you use backslash before the newline to continue.

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but why do you want to clear the screen?

Comment: @ keith: this is just a sample function, will insert more if it works

Comment: If you are learning C the above code is ok. When you get more experience you should avoid at all the system function call. This function creates a child process (a shell ,sh). This shell executes another child process (clear). Instead you can create a new process and use exec family system calls. In Unix. I dont know about Windows syscalls.

Comment: Thanks for your input David, I remember learning something about sub shells some time ago. I understand that it makes my program slower and puts on the stack unneccasary, but at the moment I just don't know any better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macro expansion should be on the same line as the macro name. If you really want them over two lines, use `\` to "escape" the newline.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define clear() system("cls");
#endif // _WIN32

#ifdef linux
#define clear() system("clear");
#endif // linux
```

or

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define clear() \
system("cls");
#endif // _WIN32

#ifdef linux
#define clear() \
system("clear");
#endif // linux
```

Comment: worked like a charm, my thanks and correct answere to you sir